# Is there a way to prevent insert for specific cases while without unique?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm setting up Postgres table to organize active store commissions in my company and I need to set a rule for preventing insert errors.

I've tried to create a table without constraints and set the rules inside a Python script. Although this solution works, It does not prevent me or others from messing around when trying to update my table.

```sql
create table my_store_commissions (
    ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
    STORE_ID INTEGER,
    COMMISSION NUMERIC,
    IS_ACTIVE BOOLEAN
);

insert into my_store_commissions
values (1,100,0.90, False),
       (2,100,0.89, False),
       (3,100,0.78, False),
       (4,100,0.78, True),

-- This code should not run
insert into my_store_commissions
values (5,100, 0.90, True)
```

I need to be able to have more than one `store_id` with `is_active = False` but only one `store_id` with `is_active = True`.

Comment: Always place the constraints in the database. Repeat after me. Applications are ephemeral; data lives forever...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a [*partial [unique] index*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html).  That is, a unique index with a filter:

```
create unique index unq_my_store_commissions_store_id_active
    on my_store_commissions(store_id)
    where is_active;
```

Note that these can be tricky to handle when switching the active store.  You may need to deactivate the previous store before setting the new one.

Comment: Thank you so much!